# MongoDB, update all values in array across multiple documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Lets say I have the following documents in Mongodb

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Sue", "grades" : [ 95, 92, 90 ] },
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Trevor", "grades" : [ 98, 100, 102 ] },
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ryan", "grades" : [ 95, 110, 100 ] }
```

I want to find all the 100's across all of this data and change to a new value.

Comment: what is the name of your collection, it will help me to write a query for you

Comment: The name of the collection is setlists

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over your array.

```
db.setlists.find({"grades": { $gte :  100, $lt : 200}}).forEach(function(doc){
   var grades = doc.grades;
  for(var i in grades) {
   (if grades[i] >= 100 && grades[i] < 200) {
      //update the value
      grades[i] = new_value;
    }
  }
 db.setlists.update({"_id": doc._id}, {$set:{"grades": grades}})
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I now get the concept of having to iterate over the array. This is javascript right?  Is there a way I can do this from the shell?

Comment: yes it's JS. you can do from the shell. If solution works pls mark the answer as correct